# Gelfand triples and isometries between dual spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V\subset H$ being a topological dense subspace of it carrying a finer topology such that $V$ is continuously embedded into $H$. Identifying $H$ with its dual $H'$, the inclusions
\begin{equation}
V\subset H\subset V'
\end{equation}
hold. The triple $(V,H,V')$ is then referred to as a Gelfand triple, and the duality pairing between $V$ and $V'$ is compatible with the inner product in $H$, in the following sense:
\begin{equation}
(u,v)_{V,V'}=\langle{u,v\rangle}\quad\text{for all }u\in V,\; v\in H\subset V'
\end{equation}
with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ being the inner product in $H$.

Now, in the case of Sobolev spaces (for simplicity in $\mathbb{R}^n$), the triple $(H^s(\mathbb{R}^n),L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for $s>0$ is known to be a Gelfand triple. In particular, there exist two isometries
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_\pm:H^{\pm s}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{equation}
such that the duality between $H^{\pm s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be realized as such:
\begin{equation}
(u,v)_{s,-s}=\langle\Lambda_+u,\Lambda_-v\rangle.
\end{equation}
My question is: does *every* Gelfand triple, without further assumptions, carry such a couple of operators $\Lambda_\pm$? If so, are they unique?

This is probably a fairly elementary question, but I am not familiar with the subject. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Lambda_+:V\to H$ is the continuous embedding. $\Lambda_-$ is an unbounded operator with $\Lambda_- : dom(\Lambda_-)=H \subset V'\to H$, $\Lambda_-u=u$ for $u\in H$.

Usually $\Lambda_+$ is not written explicitly (as all continuous embeddings are), while nobody uses $\Lambda_-$.